# What might the hashtag #JayLaGerbe mean?

Tags: vocabulaire, sms-lingo

I've tried to look it up and I can find a few references but nothing that might hint at a translations.

Comment: It is common on the net to say "Jay" instead of "J'ai". It's just a style effect to make it geek.

Comment: The first time I saw that it was "Jerry" instead of "lol" or "mdr" from user of the 15-18 forum of jeuxvideo.com. One could say it's the french version of 4chan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a pun as JayLaGerbe is prounounced the same as "J'ai la gerbe" which means "j'ai envie de vomir" in a familiar way. Jay LaGerbe could be the name of a person.